# Structuring UIViewControllers with images inside of text

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, structure

I have to create an application that has 5 `UIViewControllers`, each with big text and images inside the text. What I have done so far was to add a `UITextView` in the `UIViewController` and load with an rtf file the whole text (every text is big).

Now I have to add images inside the text in some places. What do you propose that could be the best way to construct it? I tried to add the image inside the the rtf file but it is not working properly. Since the text is too big I did not want to add the text manually by typing it. Also, I have a top bar menu that slides the view to each content, that is why I had to have only one `UITextView`. I am looking for a best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding your texts with images on UIWebView with loading these texts by  wrapping them into html?

You can also add javascript callbacks which you will be able to handle in swift or obj-c by adding JavascriptCore.framework to your build phases:

Add button in your code:

```
<button text="Close" onclick="javascript:callSwiftCode()">Call swift code</button>
```

And in your UIWebViewDelegate class:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let context: JSContext =  webView.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as! JSContext

    let codeClosure: @convention(block) ()->() = { ()->() in
        print ("This is callback from javascript you can add your code in this closure")
    }

    let casted: AnyObject = unsafeBitCast(codeClosure, AnyObject.self) as AnyObject
    context.setObject(casted, forKeyedSubscript: "callSwiftCode")
}
```

Comment: That is a very nice idea. Thank you for your response. But also one more thing. Can I add a button in the html file that opens another image? Is that possible?

Comment: That should be possible directly in the HTML. If you want to have a proper hook to your app's native code (for something different) I'd recommend using `WKWebView` and `WKUserContentController`'s `addScriptMessageHandler:name:` method to install a java script listener.

Comment: Great. I will test it and tell you my results. I am very positive that this will do my work. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do I need to change anything of this code? Because I tried in many ways to add this code and run it but the javascript is not calling the swift back.

Comment: Have you set your view contorller as delegate of your UIWebView?

Comment: Yes I have. It is working. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `NSAttributedString` and `NSTextAttachment`. Attributed strings are strings with formatting attached(bold, italics, colors, etc), but you can also attach the images inside attributed strings, and they just get drawn right along with the text. Below example might help you understand:

```
//Create a mutable attributed string so that we could append everything to it.
let bigText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your text starts here")

//Create a NSTextAttachment
let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named: "image1.png")

// wrap the attachment in its own attributed string so we can append it
let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)

// add the NSTextAttachment wrapper to our full string, then add some more text.
bigText.appendAttributedString(image1String)
bigText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "End of text"))

// Then set this bigText to your label's attributedText property.
yourLabel.attributedText = bigText
```

Comment: Yes but still, I have to enter the whole text inside the (string: ""). And my text is too large.